# Is there a difference between deployment pipeline and devops pipeline

Tags: deployment, devops

I'm presently working on my diploma thesis, which is about packaging and deploying an Android application. When I dug deeper into the subject, I came across devops, and I'm now wondering whether the devops pipeline is different from a conventional deployment pipeline. Thus, my query is: Is there a difference, and if so, what is it, and if not, then why do they resemble each other?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "conventional deployment pipeline" and "devops pipeline", really. Do you mean continuous integration pipe, or continuous delivery, or continuous deployment?

Comment: @markalex continuous intergration

Answer (score 0):

First of all, by conventional pipeline here I assume manual deployment.

CI pipeline differs from conventional in a couple of ways:

- shorter cycle - more frequent commits, more frequent integration (merges).
- After each merge - an automatic run of the unit test suite.
- Most of the time - some kind of quality gates to be merged into upstream are present when CI is used.
- Could be present security test suit (not to be confused with manual security testing, more on matter read about DevSecOps)